# Free text search over multiple tables and mulitple columns?

Tags: sql, performance

How should a SQL solution look like to do a very efficient text search via database tables and columns?

We have a requirement, that a user should be able to search via free text search for a bunch of data.
The data is separated into multiple tables and of course each table has multiple columns.
The columns are either number data types or text columns.

If the user searches for e.g.

```
Mainstreet 1013
```

We could do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE 
   columnVarcharX LIKE '%Mainstreet%' OR 
   columnVarcharX LIKE '%1013%' OR 
   columnIntegerX LIKE '%1013%'
SELECT * FROM TableB WHERE
   columnVarcharY LIKE '%Mainstreet%' OR 
   columnVarcharY LIKE '%1013%' OR 
   columnIntegerY LIKE '%1013%'
....
```

and many more.
But this is not efficient an not very easy to maintain.
We use typically H2database, MySQL and PostgreSQL.

Maybe very basic question, how is this type of problem named?

How can this problem be solved?

Are there any SQL standard solutions, to solve such type of problems?

Comment: Are fulltext search engines an option? Or do you really need the '%...%' pattern? If you need that, not a lot you can do to get better performance.

Comment: yes I am open to all suggestions to reduce complexity and to get a easy to use solution

Comment: With Postgres I can think of at least one solution, but it still won't be too pretty... What you would do is create a separate search table containing a `tsvector` typed column to enable easy searching and an `OID` (or similar) column to specify the source column/table. With that you need a few triggers per table to automatically update the search table when rows are being added/updated/removed. The Postgres manual has some examples: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/textsearch-tables.html#TEXTSEARCH-TABLES-INDEX

Comment: Ultimately though... using a dedicated search server like Solr or Elasticsearch might be a better solution for you

Comment: There is a special index type in Postgres where it _can_ use an index for such a condition: `LIKE '%1013%' ` http://www.depesz.com/2011/02/19/waiting-for-9-1-faster-likeilike/

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
 DECLARE
     @street AS VARCHAR(50),
     @integer AS VARCHAR(50)

    SET @street = 'Mainstreet%'
    SET @integer = '1013%'

    SELECT * FROM tableA, tableB
    WHERE columnName LIKE @find
    OR columnName1 LIKE @integer
```